# django + nginx custom location block not working

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I want to deploy django as backend server with nginx.

I use daphne as asgi server due to django channel

```
     location /api {
                proxy_set_header Host                   $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $scheme;

                proxy_pass                              http://127.0.0.1:10131;
        }
```

as you can see, `http://127.0.0.1:10131` is django which should be connected to `http://my_domain.com/api`

but django can't recognize requested uri.

surely, I set `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` to `/api`

What should I do further?

please help.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether your `daphne` service is running on server or not & then try this

```
server {
    listen 80; # can change to 10131
    server_name http://my_domain.com;
    location /api {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10131;
    }
}
```

You can change `listen` port if you want your api accessible to specific port eg. **10131**

---

If you're facing any issues then try to check your `daphne` logs like this

```
sudo journalctl -u daphne
```

and to check your api is running or not run this command

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:10131/api
```

you may need to install [curl](https://curl.se/) run this to install it

```
sudo apt install curl
```

Comment: `curl http://127.0.0.1:10131/api` returns 404 html page.

Comment: and I deployed with docker image including daphne. I don't use daphne in local.

Comment: So I think  your api is not running on `http://127.0.0.1:10131/api` url

Comment: I use `python:3.10.5-bullseye` image as base of my docker image though I can't execute `journalctl` :(

Comment: So can you check your api is running or not inside container or check container status `docker container ls -a`

Comment: I can't find any tag `3.10.5-bullseye` in python official image can you share me link of tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247243/discussion-between-kreimben-and-ankit-tiwari).

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/layers/python/library/python/3.10.5-bullseye/images/sha256-f4802f646ed1619dd4795e55d72c1a79ee77e51e3425c8ec1eebb4da08692865?context=explore  @Ankit Tiwari